# HTML tag inside bootstrap tag

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-5

How to use html tag inside bootstrap tag?

Here is my code:

```
 newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<label>Name'+ ' : </label>' + '&nbsp;'+'<input **str`enter code here`ong text**type="text" name="names'+ counter  + '" id="textbox' + counter + '" value="" >'+
 '<label>Telephone' + ' : </label>'+'&nbsp;&nbsp;'+'<input type="text" name="telephones' +counter  + '" id="textbox2' + counter + '" value="" >'+'<br>'
 +'<label>mobile'+ ' : </label>' +'<input type="text" name="mobiles' +counter + '" id="textbox3' + counter + '" value="" >'+
 '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'+'<label>E-mail'+ ' : </label>'+'&nbsp;&nbsp;' +'<input type="text" name="emails' + counter + '" id="textbox4' + counter + '" value="" ><input type=hidden name="contactupdate'+counter+'"  id="contactupdate'+counter+'" value=" "><hr>');
 $("#contactcount").val(counter);
```

Answer (score 0):

which bootstrap tag you want to use in `.html()` ? Explain little more.
normally you can do this, to use HTML + Class/ID in `.html()`

```
.html('<div class="col-md-2"> Name : </div>'+Name+' <div  class="col-md-2">'+Telephone+'</div>');
```

**Edited**

here is my Laravel Blade template example

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="form-group clearfix">
        {!!Form::select('receiver_username', $friendlists, null, ['id'=>'$friendlists', 'class'=>'form-control'])!!}
        <button type="button" class="btn search-btn pull-right"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::textarea('message_text', null, ['id'=>'message_text','class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Type here a message']) !!}
    </div>
</div>
```

**your JS code**

```
newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<label class="label-info">Name'+ ' : </label>' + '&nbsp;'+'<input type="text" name="names'+ counter + '" id="textbox' + counter + '" value="" class="form-control input-lg" >'+ '<label class="label-warning">Telephone' + ' : </label>'+'&nbsp;&nbsp;'+'<input type="text" name="telephones' +counter + '" id="textbox2' + counter + '" value="" class="form-control input-lg">'+'<br>' +'<label class="label-danger>mobile'+ ' : </label>' +'<input type="text" name="mobiles' +counter + '" id="textbox3' + counter + '" value="" class="form-control input-lg">');
```

Comment: Hi Qazi.  i am using twitter bootstrap  for ex:<div class="form-group">
       {!! Form::label('name', trans('noorsi.contact.name'), array('class' => 'col-xs-4 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 control-label custom_required')) !!}
       <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        {!! Form::text('name',@$contact->name,array('class'=>'form-control','maxlength'=>'255','required')) !!}
       </div>
      </div>

Comment: so what issue you are getting?

Comment: Hi Qazi  i have need .html inside <div class="form-group">
       {!! Form::label('name', trans('noorsi.contact.name'), array('class' => 'col-xs-4 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 control-label custom_required')) !!}
       <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        {!! Form::text('name',@$contact->name,array('class'=>'form-control','maxlength'=>'255','required')) !!}
       </div>
      </div>

Comment: how to use in laravel 5

Comment: I updated my answer, have a look. Did you mean this ?

Comment: No Qazi..<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="form-group clearfix">
        {!!Form::select('receiver_username', $friendlists, null, ['id'=>'$friendlists', 'class'=>'form-control'])!!}
        <button type="button" class="btn search-btn pull-right"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
    </div>

Comment: This bootstrap tag how to use in javascrtpt..?  .html inside  for ex: newTextBoxDiv.after().html( this tag)

Comment: This is my question Qazi.     newTextBoxDiv.after().html( bootstrap tag )

Comment: I told this also in my answer see third line, I have added dive + bootstrap classes in `html()` method

Comment: Hi Qazi. Sorry for the inconvenience disturbance ,actually

Comment: did you got the solution or not ?

Comment: This is my code   
     
  
       newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<label>Name'+ ' : </label>' + '&nbsp;'+'<input type="text" name="names'+ counter  + '" id="textbox' + counter + '" value="" >'+
         '<label>Telephone' + ' : </label>'+'&nbsp;&nbsp;'+'<input type="text" name="telephones' +counter  + '" id="textbox2' + counter + '" value="" >'+'<br>'
         +'<label>mobile'+ ' : </label>' +'<input type="text" name="mobiles' +counter + '" id="textbox3' + counter + '" value="" >');

Comment: actually now working in javascrip well.how to apply the same code  using  bootstrap tag

Comment: @sivakumar.s em sorry, I can't share email, you can find me on FB, Twiter, Gmail etc easily.